# What tools are out there to collect participants' browsing and/or search data as part of an experiment?

Tags: tools

I'm running an experiment where I need to collect and analyse participants' browsing and search histories. The design of the experiment is similar to an "instrumented user panel", described here:http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.8971&rep=rep1&type=pdf

In the classic case, participants must install some kind of logger on their computers, which collects and sends browsing data to the researcher behind the scenes. Finding such tools is where I get stuck.

I could, of course, just ask my participants to export their browsing histories and send them to me every night, but I was hoping there would be something more automated out there, with potential bells and whistles such as annotations.

Note: Please let me know if this is the wrong Stack Exchange; I must be really struggling with finding the right keywords for this...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for a client-side JavaScript tracking. This is often done through cookies.